# How can I securely update End User's Database with EF migration?

Tags: database, entity-framework, migration, auto-update, end-user

I have a program that runs on a wide variety of clients' computers. How can I automatically update the end-user database when I release an update of my program that I configured the migration with EF code-first? The point is, can we apply the migration feature to the end-user database **at runtime without damaging** the end-user's data?

Comment: Migrations don't delete data, so I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: The question was clear. Can I use migration as end user's database to update? Database Versioning issue.